# set tab badge from urban airship push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com, badge

My app has four tabs, each of which may "receive" a push notification. Right now I show a badge for he app at large. But when a notification comes, I would like to increment the badge of the appropriate tab. How might I route the push notification from urban airship to increment the badge of the appropriate tab?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Urban Airship's documentation? 
Setting the badge number in the app: 
http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/ios_features.html#badges

Sending a push to increment the badge:
http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/push.html#badge-values